# any other terminal than konsole with shift+mouse wheel to scroll faster?

Tags: software-recommendation

I used to have konsole installed, where you can just press shift when using the mouse wheel, which transforms the scroll from "line per line" to "page to page".
Are there any other terminals that have this feature ?

(installing konsole is a bit painful as it comes with all the KDE librairies, making it a 200MB install for just a terminal)

Thanks !
(Using Ubuntu 22.04)